# Custom Retrofit converter to nest JSON

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

I have a POJO that contains a single authentication token in a string variable. I need to send this to my API using the following template:

```
{ “auth” : { api_key”:”XXXX” } }
```

I am using moshi to convert my POJOs to JSON, which returns

```
{"api-key":"XXXX"}
```

How can I add the extra brackets on the outside of my current one using a retrofit converter?

Comment: Your JSON Is not correct..

Comment: Sorry @abhishukla, corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Moshi-Lazy-Adapters](https://github.com/serj-lotutovici/moshi-lazy-adapters) to wrap the json. Just use the following annotation when you send the body:

```
@POST("your_post_url") 
Call<YourResponseTypeHere> sendApiKey(@Body @Wrapped({"auth", "api_key"}) String apiKey);
```

The library's adapter will do the rest. And you don't need to declare an extra object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [oAuth](https://oauth.net/) authentication. Then, you can use an [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) for Retrofit and populate that token.